# Are there solids which repel fluids in contact with them?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-energy

Denoting the energy per unit area stored in the surface of a fluid due to a very close nearby solid with $-\gamma$. So that the force which points to the least energy is, for a line element on the surface,

$$d\mathbf{F}=-\gamma dl\mathbf{\hat{t}},$$

where $\mathbf{\hat{t}}$ points to the direction in which the surface element confined to the boundary $\mathcal{P}$ (and $dl$ lies in $\mathcal{P}$) extends;

Does there exist any combination of solid and fluid so that $\gamma$ happenes to be negative?

Comment: Google "anti-wetting".

Comment: it is called hydrophobic, for water repulsion . Silicon paste used for insulations is one of them http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12633-014-9188-0

Comment: @anna zero gamma will also avoid absorption. Why does not absorbing water imply negative gamma?

Comment: @sammygerbil Is that like if a fluid is forcibly injected into the solid, the solid will shoot it out?? This is more that zero gamma, which implies no interaction with the solid. This seems to be something like "super repulsion".

Comment: No, an anti-wetting agent is a coating which repels water, so that the water forms into droplets and slides off because of gravity. There is no "injection" and no "shooting out".

Comment: @sammygerbil Based on my definition of gamma, I wanted to know if negative gamma would make sense. What you describe can be explained with zero gamma. I want to talk in terms of gamma.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is zero then I think water poured onto a horizontal anti-wetting material would remain as placed, it would not break up into small droplets. There is a short-range repulsion which is counteracted by the rise in the CG of the droplet.

Comment: OH!! yes. that's the difference. I think it well fits in an answer...